# what's the key word as in sql really indicate

Tags: sql, database, self-join, table-alias

1:here is a SQL query , which i find in the book

```
 select distinct T.branch_name
        from branch as T, branch as S
        where T.assets > S.assets and
        S.branch_city = 'Brooklyn'
```

what i am confused is  T and S both indicate table branch right? why they use `T.assets>S.assets`, is it the same as `branch.asset > branch.asset` what's the difference.

2: the meaning of the following query is to "Find all customers who have an account at all branches located in Brooklyn"
[image: question2]

But I did not get it somehow, also struggle with the **as** key word

Comment: The query takes the same table twice, and make a join between them. T and S refers to the same table, but the table is copied twice into memory to resolve the query, so T and S refer to the 2 different copies in memory.

Comment: Your book is dated. Avoid using non-ansi standard join syntax. Instead of `branch as T, branch as S where T.assets > S.assets` write it as `branch AS T INNER JOIN branch AS S ON T.assets > S.assets AND S.branch_city = 'Brooklyn'`

Comment: @sturcotte06: it's probably not implemented as a copy as such, but it can logically be treated as two tables that have the exact same data as if by a copy.

Comment: thank you all above , that clears my head!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of code like this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
    for (j=0; j<10; ++j)
        print i, j
```

How can i and j not be the same value? Easy -- they are both looping over the same set of values from 0 to 9, but on each iteration of the loop, they each have a *different* value within that range of integers.

That's similar to table aliases. Think of a join like this kind of nested loop. Each time two rows are joined, S and T are *correlation names* (which is the technical term) that reference one row at a time in your `branch` table.